# .StartsWith not working as expected?

Tags: c#, if-statement, startswith

I have a url where I need to check that it does not start with http:// or https:// and the length of the url is no longer than 493 characters.

So far I have this conditional statement:

```
else if (!url.Text.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
         !url.Text.StartsWith("https://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
         url.Text.Length > 493)
    IsValid = false;
```

However this returns true when urls do have http:// or https://

Not to sure why this is?

Comment: i tested it on my local system it is going in if condition if string starts with http or https

Answer (score 3):

You need `&&` instead of `||`, suppose you string starts with `https` then first check `StartsWith("http://"` will give `true`. The same is applied if Text starts with `http`

```
else if (!url.Text.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !url.Text.StartsWith("https://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && url.Text.Length > 493)
                IsValid = false;
```

You can combine both condition with || and negate the result with !

```
if (!(url.Text.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || url.Text.StartsWith("https://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)  && url.Text.Length > 493)
```

Comment: Such a stupid mistake! Thank you! Spent ages looking at this!

Comment: I think you started thinking about StartsWith with and overlooked the condition.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `||` in to a `&&`

Answer (score 1):

Urls will either start with `http` or `https`, that means that one of them will always be true. You need to check them with `&&`

Answer (score 0):

Its the `||` and `&&` logic thats causing the problem

Re-write it as a nested `if` to make it clearer

```
private static bool IsValidUrl(string url)
{
    if(url.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || 
       url.StartsWith("https://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
       if(url.Text.Length < 493)
           return true;

    return false;
}
```